# Plot for different parameter values in a solution $u(x,t)$

Tags: plotting

How to plot a graph for $u(x,t)$, for different value of $\alpha$

```
u[r,t]=(-h*t^α)/(Gamma[α+1]*r)
```

Comment: `u[r_, t_, α_] := (-t^α)/(Gamma[α + 1]*r);

Plot[{u[r, 1, 1], u[r, 2, 2]}, {r, 0, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[u]

u[r_, t_, α_, h_] := (-h*t^α)/(Gamma[α + 1]*r);

Plot3D[
 Evaluate@Table[u[r, t, α, 1], {α, 1, 5, 2}],
 {r, 0, 2}, {t, 1, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {r, t, u}),
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotRange -> {-15, 0},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer to Mathematica Stack Exchange!